# WebDev.WebServer.EXE hangs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008-sp1, webdev.webserver

I am using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 with .NET Framework sp1. I am not using IIS but the built-in server provided by vs 2008.

I have an ASP.NET MVC project, which sometimes when started opens the browser window & just keeps on trying to load the default page. After stopping the application & killing the webserver, there's still always an instance of WebDev.WebServer.EXE running in taskmanager.

For whatever reason, I am unable to kill this process & I have no choice but to restart my system. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, i started using IIS instead of Cassini, so i don't have to deal with webdev.webserver.exe issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something in your application that causes the server to hang. Does the server hang when you try to launch any project or one specific project?

<strike>To kill the process without rebooting, use the awesome ProcMon while running as admin.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx</strike>

To kill the process without rebooting, use Process Explorer
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: i have not had a chance to test this scenario on other projects, so i don't know if this behavior is limited to just one specific project.

Comment: I guess you meant ProcessExplorer instead of process monitor. There's no way to kill a process usuing procmon.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Corrected.

Comment: I have tried that already using process explorer to no avail.

Comment: Does the server hang when you try to launch any project or one specific project?